# Getting [object Object] after calling php array with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, dictionary

I'm trying to get an array that is `json_encoded`. The array also contains dictionaries. To give you a bit of an example it looks like this **`[{key:'value'}]`** there are 5 keys and every row has the same keys but different values. There is about 70000 items in the dictionary because they were read from a file and put in a for while loop to put them in an array.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $tmp[] = $row;
}
$test = json_encode($tmp);
```

The array and dictionaries were pulled from a `MySql` table and the keys associate to the columns. My files are named `ipv4.php` and `jsIPv4.php`
so the array and dicti are defined and put in a variable in `ipv4` and are called to a `javascript` code in `jsIPv4` where I try to store it into a variable and parse it with `JSON.parse`. But before I can do that I need to at least print out the values in the array.

This is how I call my `php` variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = <?php echo $test ?>;
    document.write(test);
</script>
```

if I put it in '' it will list out everything i need but when I try to call it as an index: `test[0]` I will get out `[` as the 1. value so I'm guessing it casts into a string.

Comment: `test` is likely an object which will be output as `[object Object]` when JavaScript tries to convert it to a `string`. Try calling `JSON.stringify(test)` to convert it to a JSON string first.

Comment: `test` is an array. The argument to `document.write()` has to be a string. Try using `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Well i dont get 1 [object Object] i get 403. Thats the amout the filter gives. When i put test in '' it will display the values i want. But it gives me a whole string. I just need the array  and the dicti inside.

Comment: Do you want all the json values returned and print in a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be awesome to pass it  via jquery ajax. I have re-written a good illustration for you based on your request.

Assuming your table has column **id, username, name, email** etc.... or you can create table as follows and insert into it
for testing

```
create table users_test(id int primary key auto_increment,username varchar(30),name varchar(30), email varchar(30));
```

**insert for testing**

```
insert into users_test(username,name,email) values('nancy','nancy moore','nany@gmail.com');
insert into users_test(username,name,email) values('tony','tony moore','tony@gmail.com');
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

   <script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response){
            var len = response.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var id = response[i].id;
                var username = response[i].username;
                var name = response[i].name;
                var email = response[i].email;

                var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + (i+1) + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + username + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + name + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + email + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";

                $("#userTable tbody").append(tr_str);
            }

        }

    });

});


</script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table id="userTable" border="1" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="5%">S.no</th>
                        <th width="20%">Username</th>
                        <th width="20%">Name</th>
                        <th width="30%">Email</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "root"; /* User */
$password = ""; /* Password */
$dbname = "you db here"; /* Database name */

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
 die("Connection to db failed ");
}

$test = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM users_test ORDER BY id";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $email = $row['email'];

    $test[] = array("id" => $id,
                    "username" => $username,
                    "name" => $name,
                    "email" => $email);
}

// Encoding array in JSON format
echo json_encode($test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i tried this code and working with value

```
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $tmp[] = $row;
} 
$test = json_encode($tmp);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = <?php echo $test; ?>;
    document.write(JSON.stringify(test));
</script> 

My data output : [{"id":"1","name":"ranbir","city":"delhi","age":"35"},{"id":"2","name":"sonu","city":"punjab","age":"40"},{"id":"3","name":"ranbir","city":"delhi","age":"35"},{"id":"4","name":"sonu","city":"punjab","age":"40"}]
```